# Oh My ZSH Docker Autocompletion on OSX not working

Tags: macos, docker, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I cant seem to get Docker autocompletion working using Oh My Zsh on macOS

I have the following in my **.zshrc** file

```
plugins=(docker git brew osx)
```

The git, brew and osx autocompletion is working, if I type docker and tab I get a list of files not docker commands

I have got the docker plugin installed in the **_docker** file in **oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker** directory and can confirm the the file is version 0.3.0 and is the same as https://github.com/felixr/docker-zsh-completion

I have tried adding commas between the plugins, putting them on new lines as others have posted in other threads.

I have also removed oh-my-zsh and reinstalling still no joy

I have docker version 18.09.1

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:33:12 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:41:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

I have just tried installing on a Ubuntu machine and it works perfectly, have also tried on another Mac and had the same problem

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. All of the other oh my zsh plugins that I have installed are working except for the Docker plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling zsh & oh my zsh and reverting back to bash then reinstalling zsh followed by oh my zsh and it is now working